# group query result in which flag not included

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this

```
NAME    FLAG
---------------------------
abc     1
abc     0
abc     2
def     1
def     2
xyz     0
xyz     0
xyz     1
efg     1
```

I need query that list the name (group the result) which flag not included 0 and included 1.The result simply like below:-

```
NAME    FLAG
------------------
def     1
efg     1
```

I have tried the query but not results the same.

```
select * mytable where FLAG NOT IN (0) GROUP BY NAME;
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Also, your requirement is not clear. Do you want to include names that have flag 1 and no flag 0? How are the results grouped?

Comment: @clinomaniac yes .. select * mytable where FLAG NOT IN (0) GROUP BY NAME; But didn't get the resutl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the simplest solution I can come up with. I believe there are more elegant answers possible.

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE name NOT IN (SELECT name FROM mytable WHERE flag = 0)
    AND flag = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use NOT EXISTS clause in this way.

```
select a.*
from tbl a
where not exists 
 (select *
  from tbl b
  where b.name=a.name 
   and b.flag=0)
and a.flag=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use aggregation. The trick is to run a condition on each row, and then use an aggregate function to pick out the net result of the condition from all of the rows...

```
SELECT t.name
  FROM a_table_like_this t
 GROUP BY t.name
HAVING MAX(t.flag=0) <> 1
   AND MAX(t.flag=1)  = 1
```

The expressions in the HAVING clause are MySQL shorthand.
A more ANSI standards compliant equivalent would be:

```
SELECT t.name
  FROM a_table_like_this t
 GROUP BY t.name
HAVING MAX( CASE WHEN t.flag=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) <> 1
   AND MAX( CASE WHEN t.flag=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  = 1
```

---

To get a better handle on what this is doing, take a look at how those expressions are evaluated on each row. Remove the GROUP BY clause, and move those expressions into the SELECT list...

```
SELECT t.name
     , t.flag
     , CASE WHEN t.flag=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS `fl=0`
     , CASE WHEN t.flag=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS `fl=1` 
  FROM a_table_like_this t
 ORDER
    BY t.name
     , t.flag
```

We get something like

```
name    flag  fl=0  fl=1
------  ----  ----  ----
abc     1     0     1
abc     0     1     0
abc     2     0     0
def     1     0     1
def     2     0     0
xyz     0     1     0
xyz     0     1     0
xyz     1     0     1
efg     1     0     1
```

If we now aggregate these rows by name (`GROUP BY name`), we can use `MAX()` aggregate to pick out a `1` (if there's one in the group. Otherwise, we'll get back a `0`.)

And we can do conditional tests on the results of aggregates functions in the `HAVING` clause.